# Wordpress wp_mail() how to add a .GIF

Tags: wp-mail

I'm using wp_mail() to send e-mail from our website. 
However, we would like to include a .gif file on the body of our message.
Here's my code, but it's not working.

```
$to = $contact['Email'];
$from = 'test@test.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: Testing Mail <'.$from .'>'. "\r\n";

$subject = "Subject Text";
$customer_name = $contact['FirstName'];

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .="<p>message!</p>";
$message .= "<p>message </p>";
$message .= "<img src='img/signature.gif'>";

$message .= '</body></html>';
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the absolute path for your included image, as the receiver of the email does not have a file "signature.gif" in a folder "img" (that's where the client is going to search it)

Replace

```
$message .= "<img src='img/signature.gif'>";
```

with

```
$message .= "<img src='http://yourwebsite.com/PATH/TO/img/signature.gif'>";
```

Where *yourwebsite.com* is your website's domain followed by the complete path.

Depending on where you added your code, you can access a WordPress function, to add the domain dynamically. This is useful if you have to move your website to another domain (for a staging/developing enviroment for example).
Have a look at [get_site_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/%22get_site_url()%22).

You could use it like this:

```
$message .= "<img src='" . get_site_url() . "/PATH/TO/img/signature.gif'>";
```